# JasperReports: fillReport in Java with XML-A datasource (Olap)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, mdx, xmla, olap4j

I have a *Java* service that I generates reports with the *JasperReports 4.0.5* library. It works well with standard JDBC datasource. 
Now I am trying to run it on olap datasource, then connecting me to a XML-A server.
In the design phase with *iReport*, everything runs, but when I run it in *Java*, I get an error "NullPointerException" on execution!
I's using *olap4j* library to connect to the data source, the same one used by *iReport*
This is the code:

```
 try{
      Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
      net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.xmla-mdx", "net.sf.jasperreports.olap.xmla.JRXmlaQueryExecuterFactory");

      final Connection connection =
        DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:xmla:Server=http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll"
            + ";Cache=org.olap4j.driver.xmla.cache.XmlaOlap4jNamedMemoryCache"
            + ";Cache.Name=MyNiftyConnection"
            + ";Cache.Mode=LFU;Cache.Timeout=600;Cache.Size=100"
            + ";Catalog=Test"
            ,null, null);

    OlapWrapper wrapper = (OlapWrapper) connection;
    OlapConnection olapConnection = wrapper.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);

    String fileJrxml = "C:\\report_xmla.jrxml";

    HashMap<String,Object> hm_parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(fileJrxml);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    JasperPrint jp = null;

    jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, hm_parameters, olapConnection);

    // Done
    connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should add more details. What versions are you using? Have you tested the olap connection independently? What is the stack trace returned? These are all important for us to be able to help you; we can't really run your report, now, can we? Also, are you aware that OlapConnections do not implement the JDBC specs completly? Does the JR API use olap connections correctly?

Comment: I solved it.
Connection is via parameters without CONNECTION object.

 String url = "http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll";
 String ds = "localhost";
 String cat = "CAT";

 String fileJasper = "C:\\report_xmla.jrxml";
 JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fileJasper);
 jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters);

Thank you for your interest Luc